# Can't open xml file using tinyxml2

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I've looked through dozens of posts about this and none of them  fixed my problem.
I have this xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scene>
 <file>sphere.d3<file/>
</scene>
```

I have this very simple function that for now simply open the file

```
string* loadXML(string file){

    XMLDocument xml_doc;
    xml_doc.LoadFile("/home/pedro/Documents/CG/TP/scene.xml");
  if(xml_doc.ErrorID() != 0) {
        cout << xml_doc.ErrorName();
      return nullptr;
      }

    return nullptr;

}
```

However, it spits out

```
XML_ERROR_MISMATCHED_ELEMENT
```

No idea whatsoever why, the file is so simple.
Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: `<file/>` -> `</file>`

Comment: That.... Works. What? Why? No tutorial on xml files does that @PaulSanders

Comment: The format of a closing tag is `</tagname>`, simple as that.

Comment: My god I'm so dumb.... God

Answer (score 1):

The actual error message is explaining the problem to you: `XML_ERROR_MISMATCHED_ELEMENT`.

This just might be an oversight on your part or you need to familiarise yourself with [XML Syntax](http://xmlsoft.org/XMLinfo.html).

If you use **Microsoft Visual Studio** to open your XML file it would flag up any syntax errors you have. For example:

[image: XML Syntax error]

What's more is that the one error then cascades down to introduce other syntax errors. As you can see:

[image: XML Syntax error]

When you hover the mouse over `</scene>` it specifically states that the closing  `</flag>` element is missing.

The other benefit with writing test XML data in Visual Studio is that it will create the closing tags **automatically** for you so you can prevent this error.